# Generate Three Characters using three nested for loop

Tags: python

I created a list to store all letters of the alphabet and used three loops to iterate over the letters.
The resulting list only has 15625 elements while it's supposed to have 17576.
Also, some elements even have four characters.

```
dist = set()

thislist = ['a','b''c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v'
    ,'w','x','y','z']
for x in thislist:
    for y in thislist:
        for z in thislist:
            dist.add(x+y+z)
        
print(len(dist))
print(dist)
```

Comment: You are missing a comma between b and c.

Comment: I wish @flakes had not deleted his answer.  It was an interesting alternative way to do this.

Comment: Right, I want to elaborate on what @Alfe said. When you have an expression with two string literals that are separated with nothing but whitespace, they are concatenated. In your case, `'b' 'c'` becomes `'bc'`, so you'll just have 25 characters in `thislist`. Sure enough, 25 ** 3 == 15625.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you only forgot a comma between the string `'b'` and `'c'`, effectively making it one string (`'bc'`).  This accounts for the slightly lower number of results.

```
import string

dist = { x + y + z
         for x in string.ascii_lowercase
         for y in string.ascii_lowercase
         for z in string.ascii_lowercase }
len(dist)
17576
```

Comment: `string.ascii_lowercase == string.lowercase` ;-)

Comment: Also for the golfers. `set(map(''.join, product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=3)))`

Comment: Also for the actual golfers: `{*map(''.join,product(*[ascii_lowercase]*3))}`

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Or [`{a+b+c for a in A for b in A for c in A}`](https://tio.run/##ZYxBCsIwEEX3PcXsmqbiphuhZNFziEgaWx1pM2EyIlJ69liyUNDd@4/PCy@5kW8OgVMamWZAGViIpgg4B2LRbdZRGP3146JZ9GyDKsv9ndDvAtPl4UTpo40O8TzRc2Bn43DSTVWtxX8Dfo7bhq4Vs9i6rx2MxGABPXQZ@y@6jGsRtpioCMaAVCm9AQ)

Comment: @KellyBundy Isn't that my solution? ;-)